# Is there a way to launch Google Map form Android app just like in Iphone?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-mobile

I want to use **Google's route planning** and etc in my **android app**.
I know that IPhone developers can launch it with an url call something like this:

```
[someUIApplication openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London"]]
```

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes just fire a VIEW intent with the url geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom

For a full list of Intents of google apps you can check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

Answer (score 1):

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,   Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London"));

startActivity(intent);